# update metadata in objects when changing shared subobjects

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, object, metadata

I need advice from experience programmers as I am failing to wrap my head around this.
I have the following data structure.

```
class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, data=[], meta=[]):
        self.data=data
        self.meta=meta

class subobj(object):
    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self.data=data
```

Say, I'm creating the following objects from it.

```
sub1=subobj([0,1,5])
sub2=subobj([0,1,6])
sub3=subobj([0,1,7])
objA=obj(data=[sub1,sub2], meta=[3,3])
objB=obj(data=[sub3,sub1], meta=[3,3])
```

Now I am changing `sub1` operating on the second object as well as its metadata. **For simplicity**, I'm writing **here** via obj. vars without setter/getters:

```
objB.data[1].data+=[10,11]
objB.meta[1]=5
```

Now, `objA.data[0]` has (obviously) changed. But `objA.meta[0]` stayed the same. I want some `func(objB.meta[1])` to be triggered right after the change of the value in `objA.data` (caused in `objB.data`) and to change `objA.meta` as well. Important: this `func()` uses metadata of the changed `sub1` from objB.

I simply don't know how to make every `obj` **know** about all other `obj`s that share the same `subobj` as it does. I could make a `func()` be triggered upon having that **know**ledge. I would appreciate any hints.

Notes:

1. I want to pass those `subobj` around between `obj`s **without metadata** and let them be changed by those objs. Metadata is supposed to store information that is defined within `objs`, not `subobj`. Hence, the value of the `func()` depends on the `obj` itself, but its definition is the same for all `obj`s of the `class obj`.
2. For simplicity, this `func(metadata)` can be something like `multiply3(metadata)`.
3. I will have thousands of those objects, so I am looking for rather an abstract solution that is not constrained by a small number of objects.

Is that possible in the current design? I am lost as to how to implement this.

Comment: Um, are your subobjects going to have additional properties on them other than `data`? In your example, you modify the `.els` property of a subobject.

Comment: If you want to have a parent object be notified when a child object's property changes, you can use events, and have the parent subscribe to its children's events in the constructor. Have a look at http://python-utilities.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Sorry. I was just rewriting in a more clear way. It simply is `objB.data[1].data+=[10,11]`. `subobj`s are simply meant to hold data that is updated by different "parent" objects. But they are objs themselves.

Comment: Do you share the same value in two different subobject`.data` properties? Would a tuple instead of a list do? Also, please include `@ppperry` in your comments when replying to me on your post.

Comment: @ppperry A tuple wouldn't do since I will be changing `.data` and want the changes to be propagated to all `obj`s that hold the `subobj`.

Comment: I think that you are confused and that a tuple would do beacuse using a tuple doesn't stop you from saying something like `subobj1.data=(6,7)`. Saying `subobj1.data+=(7)` would still work, but it would modify the object the `.data` property on the subobject points to.

Comment: @ppperry you are right. Nevertheless, how would this change of design help create "auto-propagation" of changes in `subobj1` to metadata of `objA`?

Comment: Because it reduces the number of ways in which the contents of `sub1.data` could be changed. Also, could anything other than `subobj`s be part of the data of an `obj`? Can the `.data` of an `obj` change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93214/discussion-between-avx-and-ppperry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `obj`s' `data` property can only contain `subobjs` and can never change, this code should work.

```
class obj(object):
    __slots__=("data","meta")
    def __init__(self,data=(),meta=None):
        meta = meta or []
        self.data = data
        self.meta = meta
        for so in data:
            so._objs_using.append(self)
class subobj(object):
    __slots__ = ("_data","_objs_using")
    def __init__(self,data=()):
        self._objs_using=[]
        self._data = data
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
    @data.setter
    def data(self,val):
        self._data = val
        for obj in self._objs_using:
            metadata_changed(obj.meta)
```

I called the function that you want to call on the metadata `metadata_changed`. This works by keeping track of a list of `objs` each `subobj` is used by, and then creating a special `data` property that notifies each `obj` whenever it changes.